# Flexbox trouble

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently working a lot with flexboxes and have some trouble regarding the code below:

1. Why isn't the image being treated like a flexbox item
2. Why are the text items on the right, which are in another flexbox, spanning over the height of their div

```css
* {
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.categories-area {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 83.59375%;
  height: 218px;
}

.category {
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 282px;
  height: 100%;
}

.category-title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 6vw;
  min-width: 94px;
  max-width: 106px;
  height: 195px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 112, 177);
  z-index: -1;
}

.category-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: 2.943262411%;
  width: 20vw;
  min-width: 192px;
  max-width: 273px;
  height: 191px;
  border: 1pt solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.text-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="categories-area">
    <div class="category">
      <div class="category-title">
        <div class="wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 26px; font-size: 12pt;">
          <span>something</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="category-content">
        <div style="position: relative; width: 132px; height: 100%;">
          <a href="librarymain.html" title="whatever">
            <img src="resources/buchcover.jpg" style="width: 87.179487179%;" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-content">
          <span>
            <img src="resources/kleinerPfeil.svg" style=" height: 1em;"/>something
          </span>
          <br />
          <span>
            <img src="resources/kleinerPfeil.svg" style=" height: 1em;"/>something else
          </span>
          <br />
          <span>
            <img src="resources/kleinerPfeil.svg" style=" height: 1em;"/>even more
          </span>
          <br />
          <span>
            <img src="resources/kleinerPfeil.svg" style=" height: 1em;"/>a little more
          </span>
          <br />
          <span>
            <img src="resources/kleinerPfeil.svg" style=" height: 1em;"/>the last bit
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The images in front of the text are irrelevant, the buchcover.jpg is supposed to be a bookcover but for testing purposes anything should work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What image are you talking about? As far as I can tell, none of the images should be flex items because the parent of any image in your code is not a flex container. Under `text-content` your spans are flex items because they are children of it

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish here? 
Your image is inside anchor tag and you the parent is displayed `flex` you need to target the `<a ... >img</a>` not the image.
The text is spanning because the hight is set to number so where the content suppose to wrap while the parent `.text-content` is setup to column without wrap even. I changed that to `flex-flow: row wrap;` change that to column and see the difference. You need to fix all your width and hight numbers.

Check My code:

```css
body {
      font-size: 11pt;
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .categories-area {
      margin-top: 80px;

      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      width: 83.59375%;
      height: 218px;
    }

    .category {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row;

      justify-content: space-between;
      position: relative;
      width: 20vw;
      min-width: 230px;
      max-width: 282px;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .category-title {
      position: absolute;
      width: 6vw;
      min-width: 94px;
      max-width: 106px;
      height: 195px;
      background-color: rgb(51, 112, 177);
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .category-content {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      position: absolute;
      top: 26px;
      left: 2.943262411%;
      width: 20vw;
      min-width: 192px;
      max-width: 273px;
      height: 191px;
      border: 1pt solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .text-content {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      height: 125px;
    }
    .text-content>span {
      flex-basis: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="categories-area">
    <div class="category">
      <div class="category-title">
        <div class="wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 26px; font-size: 12pt;">
          <span>something</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="category-content">
        <div style="position: relative; width: 132px; height: 100%;">
          <a href="librarymain.html" title="whatever">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80/0f0" style="width: 87.179487179%;" />
              </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-content">
          <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10/0f0" style="height: 1em;"/>something
              </span>

          <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10/0f0" style="height: 1em;"/>something else
              </span>

          <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10/0f0" style="height: 1em;"/>even more
              </span>

          <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10/0f0" style="height: 1em;"/>a little more
              </span>

          <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/10/0f0" style="height: 1em;"/>the last bit
              </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```